# account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, dapps, dapp-development

I am using in the geth console and there is a similar error.

Do I add "--allow-insecure-unlock" when I "init a node"?

[image]

personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKtTW.jpg))

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

-I'm sorry :( I'm not good at English.-

Comment: run geth with  allow-insecure-unlock to bypass this protection